# How to create a custom error page in jsp for UnknownHostException

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

One of the method in my code throws UnknownHostException exception. So what i want to do is whenever this exception arises i have to show the message in a jsp page. In case of PageNotFound or InternalError exception we know the error codes so we can do that but how can we do for UnknownHostException.

Comment: can you just take the error message string and put it in any jsp template you have now?

Comment: Is there any other way like how we handle in case of 404/500 error in web.xml

Comment: You can try with try catch block and add redirect in catch block